# Why is this MongoDB loop executing more times than expected?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have this server-side JS script:

```
// Run processNames on all rows in cities
var cur = db.cities.find();
cur.immortal = true;
var j = 0;
var total = cur.count();
cur.forEach(function(obj) {
    processNames(obj);
    if (j % 100000 === 0) {
        print(j + "/" + total + " cities processed");
    }
    j++;
});
print("Completed load: " + j + " cities processed");
```

In the output, I see this:

```
...
4800000/3411205 cities processed
4900000/3411205 cities processed
5000000/3411205 cities processed
5100000/3411205 cities processed
5200000/3411205 cities processed
5300000/3411205 cities processed
5400000/3411205 cities processed
5500000/3411205 cities processed
```

How can this be happening? The cursor returns only 3411205 documents, but the forEach loop is executing over 5 million times. What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you modify documents in `processNames()` method which causes MongoDB to relocate documents. You can use [snapshot()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.snapshot/) to overcome this problem.

`var cur = db.cities.find().snapshot();`